# Major re-boot problem

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I've been using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without problem for months. A software update two days ago has generated a big re-boot problem. From a live CD I downloaded the boot repair program, but I still cannot re-boot. 
Here is the pasted report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25895261/

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:

    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   617,035,775   617,033,728  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         617,037,822   625,141,759     8,103,938   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         617,037,824   625,141,759     8,103,936  82 Linux swap / Solaris


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07   ext4       
/dev/sda5        263eb451-51ae-4384-8f4c-c064a65344f8   swap       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS amd64

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov  5 14:12 ata-HITACHI_HTS723232A7A364_E3834563KUK6VN -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 ata-HITACHI_HTS723232A7A364_E3834563KUK6VN-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 ata-HITACHI_HTS723232A7A364_E3834563KUK6VN-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 ata-HITACHI_HTS723232A7A364_E3834563KUK6VN-part5 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov  5 13:57 ata-TSSTcorp_DVD+_-RW_TS-U633F_R3476GSZ604940 -> ../../sr0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Nov  5 14:12 wwn-0x5000cca61df5e46f -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 wwn-0x5000cca61df5e46f-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 wwn-0x5000cca61df5e46f-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov  5 13:57 wwn-0x5000cca61df5e46f-part5 -> ../../sda5

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=10
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic root=UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-42-generic-advanced-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic root=UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-42-generic-recovery-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-42-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic root=UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-27-generic-advanced-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-27-generic-recovery-a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic root=UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=263eb451-51ae-4384-8f4c-c064a65344f8 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

  12.136611938 = 13.031587840   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  12.322463989 = 13.231144960   boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   1.460350037 = 1.568038912    boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic                  1
 184.964279175 = 198.603882496  boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic                  1
 184.964279175 = 198.603882496  vmlinuz                                        1
   1.460350037 = 1.568038912    vmlinuz.old                                    1
 185.884487152 = 199.591948288  boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic               3
 185.927112579 = 199.637716992  boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic               1
 185.927112579 = 199.637716992  initrd.img                                     1
 185.884487152 = 199.591948288  initrd.img.old                                 3

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 9 (/proc/13775/mounts) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 21397: bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[47922]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 21397: bash
  No volume groups found

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20171105_1412 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa64
boot-sav version : 4ppa64
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa64
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
boot-repair is executed in live-session (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, trusty, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- maybe-ubiquity
ls: cannot access /home/usr/.config: No such file or directory

=================== os-prober:
/dev/sda1:Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (14.04):Ubuntu:linux

=================== blkid:
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="a71b922f-1cfd-41dd-8a20-999e17a8ee07" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="263eb451-51ae-4384-8f4c-c064a65344f8" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.

=================== sda1/etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Nov  5 13:47 grub.d
total 76
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9791 Dec 17  2015 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6058 May 13  2015 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11608 Dec 17  2015 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10412 Dec 17  2015 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 Mar 12  2014 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 Dec 17  2015 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Jul 17 05:59 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 17  2015 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Dec 17  2015 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Dec 17  2015 README




=================== sda1/etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"




=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
SecureBoot maybe enabled.


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
sda1    : sda,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  grub-pc ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda1.

sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/sda:320GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA HITACHI HTS72323;
1:1049kB:316GB:316GB:ext4::boot;
2:316GB:320GB:4149MB:::;
5:316GB:320GB:4149MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

BYT;
/dev/sr0:1070MB:scsi:2048:2048:mac:TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-U633F;
1:8192B:24.6kB:16.4kB::Apple:;
2:53.8MB:63.1MB:9306kB::EFI:;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME TYPE FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL
sda   disk          298.1G
sda1  part ext4     294.2G
sda2  part              1K
sda5  part swap       3.9G
sr0   rom  iso9660   1020M Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS amd64
loop0 loop squashfs 975.9M

KNAME ROTA RO RM STATE   MOUNTPOINT
sda      1  0  0 running
sda1     1  0  0         /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2     1  0  0
sda5     1  0  0         [SWAP]
sr0      1  0  1 running /cdrom
loop0    1  1  0         /rofs


=================== mount:
/cow on / type overlay (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type ext4 (rw)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/sda (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 sda5 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0 (filtered):  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device discard_alignment events events_async events_poll_msecs ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev (filtered):  agpgart autofs block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri ecryptfs fb0 fd freefall full fuse fw0 hpet hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-2 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 input kmsg kvm log mapper mcelog media0 mem memory_bandwidth ndctl0 net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 sda sda1 sda2 sda5 sg0 sg1 shm snapshot snd sr0 stderr stdin stdout uhid uinput urandom v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     382M  1.3M  381M   1% /run
/dev/sr0       iso9660  1020M 1020M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0     squashfs  976M  976M     0 100% /rofs
/cow           overlay   1.9G  116M  1.8G   7% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.9G  264K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none           tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1      ext4      290G  4.5G  271G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1

=================== fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000130d2

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   617035775   308516864   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       617037822   625141759     4051969    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       617037824   625141759     4051968   82  Linux swap / Solaris



=================== Recommended repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/etc/default/grub

*******lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Latitude E6410 [1028:040a]
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
*******

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.14,grub-install (GRUB) 2.

Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
grub-install /dev/sda: exit code of grub-install /dev/sda:0

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-27-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


The boot files of [Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I still cannot re-boot"? What generated the "big re-boot problem" and what is it?

Comment: @derHugo I mean that after doing "sudo boot-repair"  from the boot repair program the problem persisted. Upon re-boot I still got the prompt "> grub rescue". I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu several times but to no avail.

Comment: @derHugo, the precise messqge I get upon re-boot is : error: file '/boot/greu/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

Comment: Sorry, I meant: error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I am experiencing a very similar issue

Comment: #Academiphile - yes I did manage to revive my system in the end after hours of trial and error, reinstalling the whole system, rebooting over and over again, getting very frustrated. But I'm afraid I really couldn't tell what single action made the difference. Try everything and anything, that has become my motto. Good luck !